# Drawbacks of holding PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK in Activity?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-service, android-lifecycle

I'm developing a Qt/C++ app for Android, that uses GUI as well as does background work (communicates with server, updating its data). The app is supposed to be always online, as it can receive a call any time and switch on the screen if needed and show GUI.

The app creates a dummy Activity to show GUI and talk to the native part.

1. Are there any drawbacks aside from battery usage, that may happen if
   I use Activity (no Service) with acquiring `PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK`?
2. Will just acquiring the lock be sufficient to run native background tasks and switching on the screen to show GUI when needed?
3. Is there a difference in terms of App lifecycle between Activity holding a lock and Service holding a lock?
4. I've read that apps with Activity compared to foreground services (`startForeground()`) can be killed if they are in background for some time. Is there a way to restart the app in background if Android kills it? I've seen only answers about restarting service-based apps.

I'm not going to use both Activity and Service because of no existing proper integration of them in QT.

Thank you